# case when join errot join in mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

hy iam to get nilai higher than 60 the print "lulus", in join mysql , but get error,, this is my
query

```
SELECT     mahasiswa.nama,
           matakuliah.nama AS nama_matkul ,
           nilai.nilai
           case
                      when nilai.nilai > 70 THEN "LULUS"
                      ELSE "not unknow"
           END
FROM       `mahasiswa`
INNER JOIN nilai
ON         nilai.mahasiswa_id = mahasiswa.id
INNER JOIN matakuliah
ON         nilai.matakuliah_id = matakuliah.id
```

table mahasiswa, nilai, matakuliah using join and get if nilai > 70 print "lulus", i get error like this

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE
> WHEN nilai.nilai > 60 THEN "The quantity is greater than 30"
> E...' at line 2

whats problem ? thanks

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT mahasiswa.nama, 
       matakuliah.nama AS nama_matkul, 
       CASE WHEN nilai.nilai > 70       -- expression firstly
            THEN "LULUS"
            ELSE "unknown"
            END AS nilai                -- then an alias to it - without table alias
FROM mahasiswa
INNER JOIN nilai ON nilai.mahasiswa_id = mahasiswa.id
INNER JOIN matakuliah ON nilai.matakuliah_id = matakuliah.id
```